# How can I regulate brightness of a LED strip with a potentiometer

Tags: circuit-design, led-strip, dimmer, brightness

I have  a 12V, 5m long LED strip and an adapter (12V 1A). I want to control the brightness of the LED strip with a potentiometer, I found a simple circuit that involves only a pot and IRFZ44N transistor.( [datasheet here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) ) It was working great, but it wasn't very bright.

When i connected the LED strip only to the adapter it was very bright but as I soldered the circuit it wasn't very bright. Also I measured that the output voltage dropped from 12V to about 9.6V.

Comment: you should use 12v 5A adapter. 14Watt/mt.

Comment: The motor driving 555 circuit  in Mark's answer with LED where motor is & driving your MOSFET would work OK. No series resistors needed with strip as it is already internal.

Comment: This does not answer the question - he is asking how to VARY the LED brightness.

Comment: @Ahmet and Passerby are making the point that LED strips may require 5 Watts per meter (this varies but that's typical enough). SO you may need an ~= 60-70 Watt power supply. The fact it was very bright is surprising - maybe it is capable of substantial;ly more than rated current when overloaded.

Comment: I noticed that C1 and C2 don't have specific "values" (can't find the exact word for this, sorry). One of them is 0.1 and the other is 0.01, but what pF, uF, mF...? @RussellMcMahon

Comment: @Tkalcec87 The values are in uF (microFarad). It is relatively common to specify values less than but near 1 uF without the units shown. This is common enough that my brain probably doesn't notice that its been done. | 0.1 and 0.01 uF are common values for bypassing (C2 here). C1 is a tining capacitor. 0.001 & no units would usually be taken as uF - but it's not safe to assume this. | 10 or 100 or 1000 without unit may be taken as uF if it seems most likely but it's less common to do that.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Okay, thanks. I will buy the components and try to build the circuit Mark sugested.

Comment: @Tkalcec87  C3 470 uF is non critical - could be 10 uF to 1000 uF . 10 uF maybe slightly small. 100 uF OK Power supply decoupling.|| Pot P1 non critical but PWM frequency varies with its value. Smaller P1 may need larger C1 IF PWM frequency is critical - which it isn't in this case. 10k OK, 47K a common value. Should be linear and not log. || R1 non critical but 1K as shown OK. Should be significantly smaller than P1. | D3 not essential for LEDs but does no harm. Use 1N400x or almost any diode about 1A rated.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I bought the components and made the PCB, can you just check if everything is ok? I used this scheme: http://reuk.co.uk//OtherImages/ne555-pwm-led-dimmer-circuit.gif

And here's the PCB: https://imgur.com/a/gMdwMr8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the mosfet should do a reasonable job of dimming your LED strip using this circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9fUaA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
this is more efficient than the 555 PWM circuit but it does cause heat in the MOSFET instead of in the strip.

But the video seems have this circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftxpUo.png)</sup>

Which isn't going to work well.

Comment: Op is using a mosfet and its not working. What are you trying to say?

Comment: the probably have the parts arranged wrong.

Comment: I built this circuit @Jasen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8e64L5RWYGM

Comment: well that exlpains why it didn't work well.

Comment: So, in theory, if I solder the circuit in the first picture it should work better?

Comment: you'll have full brightness available, but the potentiometer will be more sensitive.  most of the action will be near the middle of the range.

Answer (score 1):

A circuit using a potentiometer and transistor attempts to regulate brightness by adding resistance in series with the LED strip. As you've noticed, it interferes with the maximum brightness. Also, as you dim the strip, you'll be wasting energy as heat in the transistor.

It's much more efficient to regulate brightness by turning the LED strip ON and OFF at a rapid, repetitive rate. To control brightness, you vary the percentage of time that the strip is ON versus the time it's OFF.

You can buy one ready-made (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01C4UBMY6)). But you'll learn more if you design your own. Here's an [article](http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/lighting/led-dimmer-circuit/) with a simple design using a 555 timer and an NPN transistor. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you, I actually would rather build my own circuit than buy a ready-made one. I'm gonna buy the components tommorow and then try to build it. I will let you know if I have any other problems.

Comment: @tk you need a bigger power supply too. 1 amp isn't really enough for 5M of any color

Comment: It doesn't waste energy. it just warms the transistor instead of warming the resistors on the strip.